# Creating a 9 Patch with repeatining pattern

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

iam stuck with the creation of a nine patch for a progressbar background. 
It has a repeating pattern like a ruler-scala and that given me headache.

here is a image of what i want(at the bottom) and what i have (top).
[image: 9Patch Problem]

can someone give me a hint how to acomplish my goal?

edit: or is it generelly possible to do this with a 9patch?
my other attempt was to make a  with android:tileMode="repeat" but there i get problems with the height of my image (repeating in the second line), i need something like repeat-x.

Thanks in advance

edit2: ok i managed to do my repeating 9patch by stretching the whole repeating pattern, but its not ideal :(

Comment: I wanted this too: i have a button with pattern fill, which I want to repeat, not strech, while keeping the borders as in original. Maybe in newer android...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be overestimating the power of 9-patches. The most you could do is have a ruler image with expanding space between the ticks. You can't, however, make a 9-patch that automatically tiles parts of your image.

On the other hand, if you create a BitmapDrawable programatically, you can set the tile mode [separately](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeX%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29) for the X and Y axes.

Comment: oh cool, separately tile modes is huge. I tried your idea with only marking the the gaps between the ticks so that the rulerimages is stretched within the gaps. But the 9patch doesnt let me save this 9patch because of bad patches (because the gaps are transparent?).

Comment: Yeah, the tool doesn't seem to like transparency. Try it in on a device, it might actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this in my webview project using border image which provides both options (repeat, stretch, fill).

As webview has kind of it's own problems in android (mostly fixed element) I decided to be more android for the next project and I found out that it's not possible to have the repeated border using 9Patch. It's so awkward as it's needy but not implemented.

In a word android development area makes me crazy, one option here one option there is a usual thing here.